# install timezonedb in docker image

Tags: php, docker, timezonedb

how to set `extension=timezonedb.so` in docker PHP image?
install timezonedb in docker bash manual and add `extension=timezonedb.so` into php.ini but not worked for me.

install timezonedb in docker bash manual and add `extension=timezonedb.so` into php.ini but not worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/1123233/why-doesnt-the-timezonedb-extension-have-the-latest-data

Method 1.

```
RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && pecl bundle -d /usr/src/php/ext timezonedb \
    && docker-php-ext-configure timezonedb \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) timezonedb \
    && docker-php-source delete
```

Method 2.

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/src/pecl \
    && pecl bundle -d /usr/local/src/pecl timezonedb \
    && docker-php-ext-configure /usr/local/src/pecl/timezonedb \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) /usr/local/src/pecl/timezonedb \
    && rm -rf /usr/local/src/pecl
```

Method 3.

```
RUN apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config \
    && pecl install timezonedb \
    && bash -c "echo extension=timezonedb.so > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-timezonedb.ini"
```

The 3 methods work properly. After building the docker container, I confirm that the extension is installed and loaded properly by checking the PHP information.